# Walking a printer tree

Tags: python, tree

I'm sorry if this has been asked and answered before.  I am so new at SNMP that I don't really know what keywords to search on for this.  I need to get the values of some single nodes and also get a list of nodes at the same level.  Specifically I want the system description, and the information in the markers area.  I'm using nextcmd to do this, but it doesn't return anything if I specify the node completely.  I think this is because it considers the node provided as the node prior to what I am looking for so it returns the values after that.  So do I need to use getcmd and then follow it by a loop of nextcmd or what? 
Thanks

Comment: Please show the code you're using, the OIDs you're actually getting, and the OIDs you want. It's unclear exactly what the problem is without that info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get the sysDescr MIB object, you can either

snmpgetnext ... sysDescr

or

snmpget ... sysDescr.0

(substitute the OID of sysDescr if your utility or API does not take
symbolic names).